# How to share image with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a button for sharing a screenshot to Facebook, etc.

**Share Button :**

```
ShareButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 - 80,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 + 140 , 163, 54))
            
            ShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share-Button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            
            ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: "shareButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            
            self.view!.addSubview(ShareButton)
```

**ShareButton func :**

```
    func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
            
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
            view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
            
            let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
            
            //New Excluded Activities Code
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint]
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint ]
            }
            
 activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = vc?.view
 activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ShareButton.frame
 vc?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
```

When I press the button, I see the following in the console:

> " whose view is not in the window hierarchy! "

and nothing happens.

**What's working:**

- Screenshot saved in the gallery

**What's not working:**

- Showing `UIActivityViewContrller` to let the user choose where to share

Comment: try `presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a few days I was able to solve the problem myself.

**The correct answer :**

**Share Button :**

```
ShareButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 - 80,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 + 140 , 163, 54))

                ShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share-Button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressedShareButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view!.addSubview(ShareButton)
```

**ShareButton func :**

```
    func pressedShareButton(sender: UIButton!) {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
            view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)

            //New Excluded Activities Code
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint]
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint ]
            }

            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ShareButton.frame
            presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


            print("Share!")    
 }
```

it works perfectly! 
good luck to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the origin of the activityController:

```
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = vc?.view
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ShareButton.frame
```